# problem with spring boot 2.x kebab-case format

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In reference to below issue https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/spring-boot-starter/issues/7 . we have to change prefix to kebab-case in java files. But what if one of the dependency jar files references to a prefix in a format like @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="MY_CONFIG"). Is there a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a solution to this problem ?

I assume you're using Spring Boot 2.x. It tightened up some of the rules around relaxed binding such that the use of the canonical form (kebab-case) is now required in the `prefix` on `@ConfigurationProperties`. (Camel case, snake case, and kebab case are all still supported in application.properties files).

The only solution is to update all `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations to meet Spring Boot 2.0's requirements. In this case that'll require a change to your dependency jar. Note that a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation with a prefix in kebab-case will work with both Spring Boot 1.x and 2.x so you should not encounter any backwards compatibility problems with the change.

Answer (score -2):

It will work and you can still use camelCase or UPPER_CASE due to Spring's [relaxed binding feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).

Comment: i tried that .. it's not working .. here is the error message from spring                     APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Configuration property name 'DATASWAP_CONFIG' is not valid:

    Invalid characters: 'D', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'S', 'W', 'A', 'P', '_', 'C', 'O', 'N', 'F', 'I', 'G'
    Bean: scopedTarget.messageUtilConfigMap
    Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter
Action:
Modify 'DATASWAP_CONFIG' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.

Comment: @user2857397 Not sure that we have gotten what the other was trying to say. Have you tried to change the prefix String given in the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to kebab case, without changing the actual property's name?