# When using ConfigurationProperties with a camelCase prefix, how do I solve "Prefix must be in canonical form"?

Tags: spring-boot

I had a property configured in my yml as

```
foobar:
  baz: 7
```

and a configuration class annotated with

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foobar")
```

and everything was working fine.

The code in my organization is generally camelCase, so I renamed both the property and prefix to `fooBar`. IntelliJ is now highlighting the `prefix = "foobar"` line with the error, "Prefix must be in canonical form". What can I do, while keeping camelCasing in the yml config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282608/problem-with-spring-boot-2-x-kebab-case-format comes the closest I've seen to this situation. I was able to piece it together. But the internet seems devoid of any simple information starting from the error message.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Spring Boot supports multiple formats of property names, but encourages you to access them in a canonical way.

Per [Property Binding in Spring Boot 2.0](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/28/property-binding-in-spring-boot-2-0):

> It turns out the idea of relaxed property names is much easier to implement if you restrict it to one direction. You should always access properties in code using a canonical form, regardless of how they are represented in the underlying source.
>
> The ConfigurationPropertyName class enforces these canonical naming rules, which basically boil down to “use lowercase kebab-case names”.
>
> So, for example, you should refer to a property in code as person.first-name even if person.firstName or PERSON_FIRSTNAME is used in the underlying source.

You can keep your config yml in camel case:

```
fooBar:
  baz: 7
```

but change the access in the configuration class annotation to use kebab-case:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo-bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Canonical names** (*property names that uniquely identify a property*) should be kebab cased.

**Kebab case**: Lowercase words, connected by hyphens.

Example: `database-connection-pool-size`

The naming convention followed in the `prefix` of the `@ConfigurationProperties` should be enforcing the kebab casing.

Example:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-properties")
public record Configuration(String name) {}
```

#### TYPES OF CASINGS

There are four types of casings available, viz:

1. camelCase
2. PascalCase
3. snake_casing
4. kebab-casing

We can use any of these styling in the `application.properties` file.

#### ADVANTAGE OF KEBAB CASING

Though we can specify any of these casing in the `application.properties` file. We can access them in the `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix =` using kebab casing only. The translation from any of these casing to Kebab casing are done by the Spring Framework itself.

##### EXAMPLE

For example, through Kebab casing in the prefix

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-properties")
```

We can access any of these styling from the `application.properties` file:

```yaml
customProperties.name="XYZ"
```

```yaml
CustomProperties.name="XYZ"
```

```yaml
custom_properties.name="XYZ"
```

```yaml
custom-properties.name="XYZ"
```

### BEST PRACTICES

1. Using the Kebab casing in both the `application.properties` file and canonical names in the `ConfigurationProperties` defines a clear casing convention.
2. It promotes maintainability, clarity in your codebase ensures your code remains clean, readable, and less prone to errors.

Comment: what if property is "CAPITAL_CASING", that is all capitalized with underscore separator?  It is a common style in the industry